# Maven: Running all tests from multiple classes + one test from another class

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, automation

I have a bunch of classes that have multiple tests in them. Is it possible to run all the tests from 3 classes and then just one or two tests from another class?

I thought something like this would work but I can't get it to run:

```
mvn -Dtest=WTest,XTest,YTest,ZTest#thisTest test
```

I am wanting to run all the tests in class W,X and YTest and just the test named thisTest in class ZTest.

Comment: What happens when you run the above? Do all of the tests execute in `ZTest` rather than just `thisTest`?

Comment: No I get an string indexOutOFBounds message. If I remove ZTest#thisTest then W,X,Y run. If I remove W,X,Y then thisTest runs from Z. This is the error I get: `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1904)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.getMethod(JUnit4Provider.java:287)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:147)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)`

Comment: OK - what version of Surefire are you running (may be specified explicitly in the pom.xml or you may need to check the console output)?

Comment: I'm using version 2.16

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is actually supported. Having spent the last half hour or so looking at the source code of `JUnit4Provider` it seems that surefire will run in 'whole class mode' (when you specify the name of the test class) or 'individual method mode' (when you specify the name of the method in the test class) but not both combined at the same time.

However, I did find a workaround. You should be able to do this:

```
mvn -Dtest=xxx.xxx.WTest#*Test,xxx.xxx.xxx.XTest#*Test,xxx.xxx.xxx.YTest#*Test,xxx.xxx.xxx.ZTest#thisTest test
```

So essentially you're running the tests in 'individual method mode' using the `*Test` wildcard to specify all the test methods in `WTest`, `XTest`, and `YTest` - whist only running `thisTest` in `ZTest`. That obviously assumes that the names of the methods in your test classes end with `Test`

Note that for this to work I had to use the fully qualified class names (which is what the xxx.xxx.xxx is supposed to show).